# Sorting a list of UserProfiles in mvc3 asp.net application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sorting

I'm having trouble sorting a list of user profiles which I am passing to the view. I want to display the list of all users in a certain role and I want to sort them by familyName attribute.

I tried using OrderBy but it has no effect.

Code in the controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //get all patients
        var patients = Roles.GetUsersInRole("user").ToList();
        //set up list of patient profiles
        List<UserProfile> pprofiles = new List<UserProfile>();
        foreach (var i in patients) {
            pprofiles.Add(ZodiacPRO.Models.UserProfile.GetUserProfile(i));
        }
        pprofiles.OrderBy(x => x.familyName);   //<-this has no effect the list produced is
                                                // exactly the same it was without this line
        return View(pprofiles);
    }
```

And the View

```
   <ul id= "patientList">

        @foreach (var m in Model)
            {
                <li>
                <ul class="patient">
                 <li class="ptitle">@m.title</li>
                 <li class="pname"> @Html.ActionLink(@m.givenName + " " + @m.familyName, "View", "Account", new { @username = @m.UserName.ToString() }, new { id = "try" })</li>
                 <li class="pprofile">@Ajax.ActionLink("Profile", "PatientSummary", new { @username = @m.UserName }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "pContent"},new{ @class = "profpic" })</li>
                </ul>
                </li>         
            }
    </ul>
```

I will need to reuse this in more than one place and there could be a large number of users so not ordering them in someway would be terrible. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pprofiles.OrderBy(x => x.familyName);` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`, not sorting the array where it was called on.

You can change your code like this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //get all patients
    var patients = Roles.GetUsersInRole("user").ToList();
    //set up list of patient profiles

    List<UserProfile> pprofiles = new List<UserProfile>();
    foreach (var i in patients) {
        pprofiles.Add(ZodiacPRO.Models.UserProfile.GetUserProfile(i));
    }       
    var ordered = pprofiles .OrderBy(x => x.familyName);   

    return View(ordered );
}
```

Or in a more Linq-styled way :

```
var orderedPatients = Roles.GetUsersInRole("user")
                           .Select(u=>ZodiacPRO.Models.UserProfile.GetUserProfile(u))
                           .OrderBy(u=>u.FamilyName);


return View(orderedPatients);
```

Or :

```
var orderedPatients = from u in Roles.GetUsersInRole("user")
                      let userProfile = ZodiacPRO.Models.UserProfile.GetUserProfile(u)
                      order by userProfile.FamilyName
                      select userProfile;
return View(orderedPatients);
```

Comment: More precisely `OrderBy` will return an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Ah, nice! I went for the Linq-styled way and it works like a charm. Thank you! Could you explain how it works in detail? I'm guessing Select traverses the list of users and gets their profiles... or does it change the returned list of users into a list of UserProfiles?

Answer (score 2):

OrderBy does not modify the order of `pprofiles` elements, rather it returns a new collection with the elements ordered. You can try this:

```
pprofiles = pprofiles.OrderBy(x => x.familyName);
```

Or you can use [List(T).Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign it back to your variable, `OrderBy` returns  sorted collection:

```
pprofiles = pprofiles.OrderBy(x => x.familyName);
```